# How to setup the screen size with dbus-run-session

Tags: wayland, gnome-shell

When I debug a gnome shell extension, the [gjs official documentation](https://gjs.guide/extensions/development/creating.html#enabling-the-extension) tell me use this command to test the new extension.

```
dbus-run-session -- gnome-shell --nested --wayland
```

But I got a `800x600` screen, so how can I change the screen size. `man dbus-run-session` no help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can be done by passing variable

```
env MUTTER_DEBUG_DUMMY_MODE_SPECS=1024x768 \
dbus-run-session -- gnome-shell --nested --wayland
```

as described [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/627015/how-does-one-run-gnome-shell-in-a-window-nested-session)

But I steel not found how to position nested wayland window